# Special relativity thought experiement

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, reference-frames, time-dilation

Say you see a spaceship moving relative to you. On this ship you see a timer. When a beam of light is emitted from one end of the ship the timer starts. When the light reaches the other end of the ship the timer stops at one second (pretty long ship, I know). If the timer is slowed down due to time dilation and the light is not, does this mean a stationery observer sees the light reach the end of the ship before the timer stops?

Comment: Dude, the speed of light is **invariant**.

Comment: Ray, in special relativity, time dilation follows from (is a result of) imposing the constancy (invariance) of the speed of light c for inertial observers.   
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Simple_inference_of_time_dilation_due_to_relative_velocity

Comment: I'll make the question more specific to show why this is confusing to me

Comment: Not quite what you asked, but related: In general in special relativity, if any two events coincide *at the same location* then that coincidence is universal. So for example to discover time dilation, it's common to think about bouncing a laser pulse from the floor to the ceiling in a train, so the timer is at both the "light emitted" and "light detected" location. Similarly, length contraction can be done by bouncing light off a mirror at the front of the train, in its direction of motion. Only after you understand these do you get to the "relativity of simultaneity," which is your question.

Comment: Can I just say I like Chris' usage of the phrase "In general in special relativity"? I think I'm going to work something like "Generally in special relativity, or rather, specially in general relativity..." into more of my posts from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word: yes.

(Edit: in rereading your question, I see you didn't specify which direction the light pulse travels (front-to-back or back-to-front). I'm going to assume front-to-back in order to have a definite answer as the other way depends on how fast the spaceship is traveling.)

The first thing to notice is that the light pulse will be traveling at $c$ (186,000 miles/second or 300,000 km/second) in the stationary observer's frame. The light pulse is also moving in the opposite direction of the space ship (nose to tail). From these two facts, we can conclude that the light pulse will reach the tail of the spaceship in less than one second in the stationary observer's frame.

In addition, the spaceship's length will be shorter in the stationary observer's frame, so the light pulse will reach the tail even earlier.

Finally, the timer on the spaceship will run slower according to the stationary observer, so the light pulse will reach the back of the spaceship before the timer goes off.

In general, events that are simultaneous to one observer will not be simultaneous to another observer with differing motion.

Comment: I managed to find a video that answers my question, but thank you for answering anyway, however since questions always lead to more questions, I have something else I want to understand about time dilation http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165467/can-surrounding-masses-influence-the-speed-of-time-excluding-the-time-dilation would you care to answer this too?

Answer (score -1):

If we ignore the motion along with the spacecraft, then most motions inside a relativistic spacecraft are slow-motion motions.

So an observer observing a moving spacecraft sees light beams move inside the spacecraft like this:

From the floor to the ceiling: Motion slowed down by amount: The time dilation factor.

From the front to the tail and then back to the front: Motion slowed down by amount: Time dilation factor squared.

From the tail to the front: Motion slowed down a lot. Travel time approaches infinity as speed of spacecraft approaches c.

From the front to the tail: Motion speeded up. Travel time approaches zero as speed of spacecraft approaches c.