# Can surrounding masses influence the speed of time (excluding the time dilation due to gravity)?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ev9zrt__lec @6:22-7:22

If you removed the middle and front spaceships, will the time of the last spaceship flow differently? As this is what it appears to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Time will flow the same way as in the video for the last spaceship whether or not the other two spaceships are there. The purpose of having three spaceships in the video is to make it easier to reason about what's happening to each observer's experience of space and time. If you watch the part at 8:22, you'll see how you can treat all spaceships as if they were a part of a larger whole, and experience the same effects.

Comment: I do not understand. Assuming by 'same way' you mean slow as the last ship is in the video, does this not mean that the ship at the front will go faster relative to the other ship even if the other ship is not there?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "go faster." In the video, the spaceship in front (from Sarah's point of view) has a clock that is ahead of the one in back, but all three spaceships have clocks that run at the same rate because they are all traveling at the same speed.